# HBase connection failure when setting HBase as the storage backend of JanusGraph in local environment

Tags: hbase, janusgraph

I first set a standalone HBase locally and I can create tables there and make queries.
Then I set JanusGraph locally using docker image. I followed official documentation for both. I think I didn't miss anything there. they work perfectly individually.

Then when I try to connect the HBase from Gremlin console. connection is refused and it  continues to retry connection. the error messages are as follows:

```
  2 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
  3      at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
  4      at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:714)
  5      at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
  6      at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141)
  7 21:31:46 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ReadOnlyZKClient  - 0x3b97907c to localhost:2181 failed for get of /hbase/hbaseid, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 3
```

The my HBase *hbase-site.xml* file is in the following format from official documentation:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///home/testuser/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/testuser/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.unsafe.stream.capability.enforce</name>
    <value>false</value>
    <description/>
</property>
</configuration>
```

The command I use to connect HBase from Gremlin is:

```
JanusGraph graph = JanusGraphFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "hbase").open();
```

Thanks for your help in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. The janusGraph I used in docker probably is a lightweight version. Some configuration details may be missed.  By installing janusgraph-full-0.5.1, follow the official Janusgraph server instruction and using

```
bin/janusgraph.sh start
```

Solved that connection problem.